# MongoDb update array element with multiply on array keys

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo document as follows

```
{
  "id": "mongoId",
  "results": [
    "score" : 80,
    "details": {
        "credit": 2,
        "creditPoints": 40,
        "creditScore": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update all documents the `creditScore` as `credit * creditPoints`.

What i have tried till now  is

```
db.match.updateMany({}, { "$set" : { "results.$[].details.creditScore":   {"$mul" : { "$results.details.credit": "$results.details.creditPoints" } } }}  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct update is not allow to use internal fields operations, you need to use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `results` array
- `$multiply` to multiply `credit` and `creditPoints`
- `$mergeObjects` to merge `details` object with updated `creditScore` field
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with updated `details` object

```
db.match.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      results: {
        $map: {
          input: "$results",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                details: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    "$$this.details",
                    {
                      creditScore: {
                        $multiply: [
                          "$$this.details.credit",
                          "$$this.details.creditPoints"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eiIl8cRAMJ9)